# Why is a razor view of my servicestack site displaying the metadata page on azure only?

Tags: razor, azure, metadata, servicestack

I have an application that displays my razor views of servicestack endpoints as expected on localhost. However when deployed to azure websites a particular page displays the metadata page for some reason. I don't know how to work out what has gone wrong as it all works on my machine :).

For reference, the view name matches the return DTO. I've tried the site in release mode on my machine. All other pages display as expected on azure and locally. I've cleared the cache and re-started the site from the control panel. I'm running out of things to try.

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some general troubleshooting approaches that might help you:

1. Use [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm), [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) or [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to watch the HTTP traffic between your computer and the website, looking for clues in HTTP headers, requests and responses.
2. Using [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/), connect to your website via FTP. Download the content of `/site/wwwroot` to a new directory on your local machine. Add this as a virtual website in IIS and run it locally. You'll be running exactly the same code that is deployed.
3. Instrument your application with tracing in a similar fashion to [ASP.NET Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x5wc973%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and look for exceptions or any other odd behavior.
4. Refer to [Troubleshooting a Web Site](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/best-practices/troubleshooting-web-sites/) for additional resources.

Comment: Thanks - I've marked it as the answer because it made me look at the deployed files - it turns out the cshtml view was missing!

Comment: @Codescribler that happened to me as well, the problem was that the Build Action of default.cshtml was set to 'None' instead of 'Content'